# Need to add an existing User to a Project_Model.User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a project management system where users and projects have a has_and_belongs_to_many association. A login'd user can create projects, and it lists only the projects they are a part of.

Here's my issue, when the project is created, I need it to add the already existing, currently logged in user that created the project, to this project's project_model.user database.

How would I do this? Would I use something like project_model.user.create!(current_user)?

This is basically what I'm having to deal with in this project in general, being able to add already existing users in the database to certain projects, specifically into their project_models.users database.

(And yes, project_model is the actual name when it should be just project. It's a group project and it wasn't my decision)

Comment: Show the code of creating a project

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating your project I imagine you're doing something like this:

```
ProjectModel.create(project_model_params)
```

Instead of creating the project in that way, you can build it from the `current_user`'s project association:

```
@new_project = current_user.project_models.build(project_model_params)

if @new_project.save
   ...
```

That way, the new project will already be set up with an association to this user when it is initially saved.

### Update

Assuming you already have a project and just want to add a new user to it, you can do it as follows:

```
# First, find the project you want to add users to
@existing_project = ProjectModel.find(params[:id])

# Next, find the user you want to add 
@user = User.find(params[:user_id]) # again - find the user however you like

# Finally, add the user to the project
@existing_project.users << @user 

# note that this will auto-save the association.
# There is no need to call @existing_project.save afterwards
```

Comment: And what about adding other users to that project's project_model.user list?

(In fact, this way was already set up by another user, but I was not aware that this added the project that was in user.project_model being created to that own project's project_model.user list, if that's what's actually happening?)

Comment: I think it's probably worth you doing some reading and learning how this stuff works. If you get an error and can't work it out, ask a specific question about it on this site. I'm not going to write your code for you, and you'll learn nothing if you don't start working things out yourself.

Comment: Wasn't asking you to write my code for me. I just wanted to know about my original question. It wasn't about at the moment of creation but about how you generally would add a user from the database into the project_model.user list. That's all.What you told me isn't what I really needed to know. Now, if you knew any guides on this subject specifically that could teach me about that I'd be happy to read it.

Comment: I've added an example for you. You should go read this page now and try out some of the examples - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: When making that example, does that work for all versions of ruby? I just ask because I've seen some things done differently for different versions (so I'm not sure what << does in mine?) Also is it possible to declare these things in the view or must they always be declared and assigned in the controller?

Comment: `<<` is an active record method. Not something specific to a version of ruby (See documentation here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C), so yes, it'll work for you. As for doing it in the view, no don't do it.

Comment: Hmm, odd. The project_model.user list still seems to be empty. I even did this in the controller:     @project_model = current_user.project_models.build
    @project_model.users<<current_user